# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_components'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I'm trying to apply [`LatentDirichletAllocation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) on a dataset. When I try to assign a value to the `n_component` argument of LDA. I get the below error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6f5cf163fcaf> in <module>()
     23 # tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(line)
     24 # print(tfidf)
---> 25 lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components = 100)
     26 lda.fit(bag_of_words)
     27 tf_feature_names = vector.get_feature_names()

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_components'
```

Comment: What version of `scikit-learn` do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 0.19

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using an older version of sklearn (< 0.19) you should use the `n_topics` arg in place of `n_components`

```
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=100)
```

The documentation for the older interface is available in [`sklearn.LatentDirichletAllocation` version 0.18](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. But I'm not sure why it is not accepting n_components because I'm using version 0.19.